# Missing @property functions from metaclas in my Enum, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, enums

I don't really like an implementation detail from Django's `ChoicesMeta` so I wanted to create my own enum metaclass that would fix that behaviour. In essence, this is what I wrote:

```py
from django.db.models.enums import ChoicesMeta as DjangoChoicesMeta

class ChoicesMeta(DjangoChoicesMeta):
    def __new__(metacls, classname, bases, classdict, **kwds):
        # Here the code to fix the behavior I don't like
        return super().__new__(metacls, classname, bases, classdict, **kwds)

class ChoiceEnum(Enum, metaclass=ChoicesMeta):
    pass

class SomeEnum(ChoiceEnum)
   ONE = "some enum value 1"
   TWO = "some enum value 2"
```

But then, when I wanted to use the property `.choices` [that comes from `django.db.models.enums.ChoiceMeta`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/enums.py#L45-L48), I get an `AttributeError`:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.10/enum.py", line 437, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: values
```

even though I can access to the property `.__members__` that comes from `ChoiceMeta`'s parent `EnumMeta`.

Cant someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check the django `ChoiceEnum` (or `Enum`) class -- that's probably where they have a `.values` attribute.

Comment: No, [`.choices`,, `.labels` and `.values` all come from `ChoicesMeta`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/db/models/enums.py#L45-L56)

Comment: Temporarily modify your `/usr/lib64/python3.10/enum.py` and remove the `from None` on line 437 -- that will give a full traceback that should have more clues.  (If you can't modify that system file, copy it to your directory so the copy gets imported instead.)

Comment: Sadly, that didn't bring more informations.

Comment: Was the traceback the same?  If different, add the expanded traceback to your question.

Comment: Traceback is exactly the same, yes.